# If $X \text{~ unif { -1, 0, 1}}$ and $Y = |X|$ are they independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm not sure how to prove they are independent since I got the joint PMF of X and Y through multiplying the marginal PMFs. So $P[X,Y] = P[X]P[Y]$ already. 
$P_x[-1], P_x[0], P_x[1]$ each is $\frac{1}{3}$
and 
$P_y[1] = \frac{2}{3}, P_y[0] = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Notice that $\Bbb{P}(Y = 1\mid X= 1) = 1$ but $\Bbb{P}(Y = 1\mid X= 0) = 0$. This cannot heppen if they are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not independent.

$P[Y = 0]P[X = 1] = \frac{1}{9} \ne 0 = P[X=1,Y=0]$

This violates the definition of independence.

It is not valid to form the joint PMF by multiplying the marginal PMFs unless the random variables are independent.